# Method @Secured supposed to throw error when no user authenticated

Tags: spring, gwt, spring-mvc, spring-security

The code for my service follows...

```
@Controller
@GwtRpcEndPoint
public class ServerServiceImpl implements ServerService {

  @org.springframework.security.annotation.Secured("ROLE_ADMIN")
  public String runGwtSprMvcHibJpaDemo(String s) {


        System.out.println("SecurityContextHolder.getContext()="+SecurityContextHolder.getContext());
        System.out.println("SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()="+SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication());
  }

}
```

my applicationContext.xml

```
<security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" jsr250-annotations="disabled" />
```

but when i call the serviceImpl through gwt-rpc, aren't runGwtSprMvcHibJpaDemo supposed to print out security error since user not yet authenticated? Rather, the method runGwtSprMvcHibJpaDemo is executed with output

```
 SecurityContextHolder.getContext()=org.springframework.security.context.SecurityContextImpl@ffffffff: Null authentication  SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()=null
```

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
<security:http auto-config="true">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
</security:http>
```

to your xml config and see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

Define bean in your spring context like:

> bean id="**userDetailsService**"
>   class="packagename.MyUserService">.

Please note that bean name should be extactly same. Spring use this bean internally to start this service.

MyUserService is a implementation of UserDetailsService.